# Weird block of color in navigation bar with certain colors in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

When I use colors like black87 (first image) or black54, I get a weird line one the nav bar, it doesn't happen with other colors. Also, when I set it to transparent, it just looks the same as the true black version (image 4).

Examples:

[image: Black87]

[image: Bluegrey]

[image: Yellow]

[image: Black]

[image: Red]

Part of the code where I change the colors:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home,
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
        ),
            title: Text('Home', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.greenAccent)),
        ),

      //same thing for each nav bar item

  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
      iconSize: 30,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
      elevation: 7
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Well, why does it happen with that color and how do I fix it?

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: Looks like a weird rendering artifact. Does it happen on multiple devices?

Comment: Actually no, it only happens on this Pixel 4XL Android Q @EdwardvanRaak

Comment: Would be interesting to see what happens if you change the color hex values just slightly

Answer (score 1):

Those values of Black are including some opacity.
Black54 is black with 54% opacity for example !

I guess you're probably seeing another widget behind your bottom nav bar and it explains the "weird line"

Comment: That makes sense, but why doesn't it happen on other devices, or even with lighter colors like grey[900]?